# SetConsoleTextAttribute : Foreground only

Tags: c++

I would like to change ONLY the foreground color text of my console application, not the background text color nor the console background color. In Other words: I want to keep previous colors like they are except the foreground text color.

Presently i use the code below but the background under the text change too.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_GREEN);
    cout << "green?" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You changed the background to black.  You need to specify both, so use the existing background color as well.  As chris hinted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background colour as well (otherwise it will go to black)
For example:
Green writing on Red background (note: use the bitwise OR operator | )

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_RED);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` to retrieve the current colour attributes, and change the foreground only.

The following, albeit untested, should work no matter what background colour you start off with:

```
HANDLE outputHandle = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); //used twice
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX cbie; //hold info

//article didn't say this was necessary, but to be on the safe side...
cbie.cbSize = sizeof (CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX);

GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx (outputHandle, &cbie); //get info

//first, cancel out all foreground attributes
//then, set the ones you want (I use bright red)
cbie.wAttributes &= 
    ~(FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
cbie.wAttributes |= (FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);

SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx (outputHandle, &cbie); //pass updated info back
```

Comment: `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` does indeed require you to set `cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX)`; otherwise `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` fails. I guess `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` fails too. 

I tried to follow your code; all calls indicate no error, yet my output is not colored. Any ideas?

Comment: @JulianKirsch, I don't have any immediate ideas. You could ask a new question with a [mre] showing the error checking and the results you get and link back here to show you've tried searching.